# What is the difference between "Window" and "page" in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

What is the difference between "Window" and "page" in silverlight? If I want to embed a page/ window inside another page/ window. How can I do that? For example, when an "Expand" button is clicked, if I dont want it to link to a totally new page, instead, I just want it to show a form embedded in the page / window.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution to this question would be to handle the click event and set the visibility property on the elements you want to show/hide in the event handler.

The link that @Robert provided is about "navigation" in silverlight, you can achieve your end goal using it and if you're planing a large application i'd say it's definately something you should look at but it'is a fairly complex subject.

Depending on your current level of silverlight knowledge and the scale of what you're trying to achieve with your silverlight application it might or might be better to take the simpler button click approach.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article.  I think it will help you achive what you're trying to do.
http://jesseliberty.com/2008/05/31/multi-page-applications-in-silverlight/

Comment: Thanks, the web page is useful. However it seems like it directs a page another page. I wanted to have a "frame" page, and have a few other "contents" page. Such that the "frame" of the page does not change, only the contents of the page changes. I hope that makes sense. Thanks again :)